# What is root reference?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

```
class GCTest {
     static Object r1; 

     static void Main() {
         r1 = new Object();
         Object r2 = new Object();
         Object r3 = new Object();
         System.GC.Collect(); // what can be reclaimed here ?

         r1 = null;
         r3.ToString();
         System.GC.Collect(); // what can be reclaimed here ?
     }
    }
```

// code from - DonBox's Essential .Net

Comment: BTW, this is a ".NET" topic, not a "C#" topic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It's like when you say .Net the world associates C# by default :)

Answer (score 3):

At the first line, there are no further references to `r2`, so this object could be reclaimed at this point. At the last line, the object created for `r1` no longer has a reference, and the local variables `r2` and `r3` are finished with, so all three objects could be reclaimed at this point. However, this will depend on how it is all compiled.

The three are all root references, as nothing else refers to them. Had `r1` been an instance field rather than a static one, then a reference to your `GCTest` class would have made the `r1` reference **not** a root reference.

Comment: Note that if you're running under the debugger, the local references will be artificially extended to last for the whole method, so that you can inspect variables.

Comment: @David - Why r2 is reclaimed in 1st call ? Why not r1 ?

Comment: I thought on the 1st call r2 should not be reclamed because *there is* a reference on *the stack*. What "no further references" means? Is GC really that smart to take into account the rest of code?

Comment: `r2` nay be reclaimed, it depends on how smart the compiler is. Similarly `r1` actually, but this requires a slightly different level of "smartness"

Comment: A smart compiler should not create the reference r2. Then, yes, the object from that line should be collected on the 1st call.

Answer (score 2):

Try your code with WeakReference and you will see, when these references are alive. Try also to go outside your method. GC only reclaims `r1`. WeakReference can give you better insight, when your references go dead.

The response with exception is of course a nonsense. The only exception that can `r3.ToString()` rise is null reference exception, but iff `r3` is null.

Comment: Hi Karel,
Can you please post the code which you are talking about.

Comment: It can't be formatted in the comment :(

static WeakReference wr1;
 
public static void MethodA()
{
  object r1 = new Object();
  wr1 = new WeakReference(r1);
  
  Console.Out.WriteLine("r1 = {0}, wr1.Alive {1}", r1, wr1.IsAlive); //wr1 is alive
}
 
public static void RunSnippet()
{
  MethodA();
  Console.Out.WriteLine("wr1.Alive {0}", wr1.IsAlive);  //wr1 is alive
  GC.Collect();
  Console.Out.WriteLine("After GC: wr1.Alive {0}", wr1.IsAlive); //wr1 is not alive
}

Answer (score 2):

The GC may collect whichever object for which it can *prove* that it makes no difference for the application. One way to think about it is the following: objects are allocated *forever* but the implementation is allowed to reclaim memory as long as it makes sure that you cannot notice it.

In your example, at the first `GC.Collect()`, the first object reference has been written to `r1`, and `r1` is a static variable, thus somehow "permanent". From the point of view of the GC, just about any code could use that static variable, so the GC cannot make sure that the first object will not be used. Therefore it cannot collect it. The second object, on the other hand, is written in a *local* variable. The local variable is limited to the method code (it disappear when the method exits) and the GC is able to notice that `r2` will not be used anymore (the GC only needs to look at the method, not the whole code, so this is part of what the GC can reasonably do). Therefore, the GC *may* collect the second object (there is no obligation here).

The third object will still be used after the first `GC.Collect()`: its `ToString()` method is called. Hence the GC should not collect it. However, it is conceivable that the VM notices that this is a true `Object` instance (not any other class), inlines the call to `ToString()`, and further concludes that the whole `ToString()` call is an elaborate way of doing nothing (no visible outcome). As such, the GC *might* be able to collect the third object and skip the call to `ToString()` altogether.

Of course the GC is free not to collect things as well. The whole point of the GC is that it runs "behind the scene", without impacting the code execution (this is not entirely true in presence of finalization, but that's an extra layer of complexity which should not be envisioned until you master the basics).

Wilson's [article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.2438&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is indeed a must-read for anybody wishing to understand what garbage collection does.

Answer (score 0):

To me it means the first object in a reference chain. ie A refers to B and B to C etc. A is a Root as nothing else refers to it.

At the first one.

r1 Is static and GC test is holding a reference to it so cannot be collected, while r2 can be collected. r3 will be unless you're in a Debugger or GC.KeepAlive is called

At the second one

r1 can be collected as it no longer in scope
r2 is already collected
And dependent on whether r3 was collected, it may have raised an exception, or will be collected.

Comment: Why do you think it would raise an exception ?

Answer (score 0):

- object that allocated in Main() and assigned to r1 will be collceted because it's unreachable after r1 set to null.
- r2 and r3 are local variables in Main() and therefore they are roots in this context.

Comment: Your comment for r1 is incorrect I think. There's a difference between a static object and a static method.